# picking out a single part of a JSON array

Tags: json, api, discord.js

I have no real experience with JSON besides some simple custom discord backgrounds where I added an image to the BG on my phone.

Currently I am making a command for a discord bot to pull information about an account using its username; so far I've had no issue pulling from the APIs because all the arrays so far have been super SUPER simple, but I'm currently trying to pull an outfit thumbnail from a users outfit id in a reliable manner.

the JSON that is giving me issues is as follows:

```
{"filteredCount":4,"data":[{"id":10402299722,"name":"aight","isEditable":true},{"id":37916403,"name":"Boy","isEditable":true},{"id":27433379,"name":"Best one so far","isEditable":true},{"id":27433333,"name":"Batpire","isEditable":true}],"total":4}
```

Specifically I am trying to pull the first ID to pop up in the text, and with no experience with JSON my first idea was "$.filteredCount.data.id" to pull the id so I could pass it along as a temp variable to another API. That API would then generate a link to the thumbnail but this didn't work as expected so I decided to ask here for help. Any help at all would be amazing thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the solution was `x.data[0].id`

it made it easier when I put the JSON through a "beautifier"

`{ "filteredCount": 4, "data": [ { "id": 10402299722, "name": "aight", "isEditable": true }, { "id": 37916403, "name": "Boy", "isEditable": true }, { "id": 27433379, "name": "Best one so far", "isEditable": true }, { "id": 27433333, "name": "Batpire", "isEditable": true } ], "total": 4 }`

doing this made it easier to understand as well as a lengthy tutorial.